# Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x0) issue generated

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, mqtt, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Paho MQTT (Internet of Things) With mobilefirst 7.1 for my hybrid application development (For iOS ,Android and windows phone devices). I tried with **'broker.mqttdashboard.com'** for MQTT broker, but its not working for iOS .

### error:

[image]

### Xcode console:

> libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!

### main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
     MQTTconnect(); //connect broker with subscribe 
}
```

### mqttService.js:

```
var host = 'broker.mqttdashboard.com';
var port = 8000;
var topic = 'Sensor';   // topic to subscribe to
var useTLS = false;
var username = null;
var password = null;
// username = "Nazmul";
// password = "Kp0582!";
var cleansession = true;   

var mqtt;
    var reconnectTimeout = 2000;

    function MQTTconnect() {
        mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(
                        host,
                        port,
                        "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100,
                        10));
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            useSSL: useTLS,
            cleanSession: cleansession,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
            onFailure: function (message) {
                console.log("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage + "Retrying")
                setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
            }
    };

        mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
        mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

        if (username != null) {
            options.userName = username;
            options.password = password;
        }
        console.log("Host="+ host + ", port=" + port + " TLS = " + useTLS + " username=" + username + " password=" + password);
        mqtt.connect(options);
    };

    function onConnect() {

        console.log('Connected to ' + host + ':' + port)
        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic
        mqtt.subscribe(topic, {qos: 0});

    };

    function onConnectionLost(response) {
        setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);

        console.log("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage + ". Reconnecting")

    };

    function onMessageArrived(message) {

        var topic = message.destinationName;
        var payload = message.payloadString;

        console.log( topic + ' = ' + payload)
        alert(topic + ' = ' + payload);

    };
```

MobileFirst: version 7.1.0.00-20151114-1616

xcode: Version 7.2 beta (7C46t)

iphone 6s plus

project uploaded here: https://github.com/nazmulkp/Mqtt-MobileFirst-Hybrid-Application

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a null reference error that the editor didn't catch - it ran only in code available on the iPhone.

Null reference errors: because always javascript file did not load. object throwing this error.

Now this way it is working

### main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit(){

      $(document).ready(function(){
           MQTTconnect(); //connect broker with subscribe         
       });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your appdelegate class name. Is it MyAppDelegate. If so, **import MyAppDelegate.h** over it. If still it isn't working then replace your code by this code.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```